# Jquery event calendar type calendar in asp.net or winform

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, winforms

I'm working on my project in which I'm making a shedual for my daily tasks. 
Found this JQuery event calendar http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/

the problem is that it is in PHP and m purely asp.net lover. :(
I not asking for help to convert this for me in asp.net version but what I want is that please tell me some control like this i you know in asp.net or in winform but in .net.

or tell mw what I have to do if I want to make this in win form calendar? can I customise it like this?
can I show more than one selected/ Highlighted dates in one calendar in win form?

Comment: asp.net are webforms not winforms

Comment: i guess he/she asking for solution in any one version, either in asp.net or windows application (winform) as he/ she only knows .net :)

Comment: Yes @Singleton , i want solution in any one case :)

Comment: This control is NOT php it's jQuery. Big difference. You can use it in asp.net

Comment: @MUG4N what i am sying is that , it uses PHP for picking data from database. I know it is in JQuery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just converted that by myself :). I wrote a ashx handler that will be responsible of giving data from databse .